# Type: Property Does not exist on Model in RXJS 6 map with angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-services, rxjs6

I have a service call and fetch the service and getting the result.while running the application with type , i am getting below error.

Error is ProductTypes property Does not exist on DataModel.

if i provide any in the below line working fine i have change to this

```
   return this.http.get<any>(SERVICE_URL).pipe(
```

Error is in this line with type:

```
  return res.ProductTypes.map((item:DataModel) => {
```

Service code:

```
fetchProduct(): Observable<DataModel[]> {

    return this.http.get<DataModel[]>(SERVICE_URL).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res.ProductTypes.map((item:DataModel) => {
          return this.Mapper(code, details);
        });
      }),
      catchError(error => this.handleError(error,'error'))
    );
  }
```

Model:

```
  import { ProductType } from './product-type-model';

export class DataModel {
  code?: string;
  ProductTypes?: ProductType;
}
```

Json response from server

```
 {
    ProductTypes:[
      {
        "code":'',
        "details":'name'
      },
      {
        "code":'AS',
        "details":'Laptop'
      }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: From server your should get DataModel array with "code" and "ProductTypes" prop, and not ProductTypes array.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you DataModel is not in sync with server response Object:

```
export class DataModel {
  code?: string;
  details?: string;
}
```

By the way what is in here `import { ProductType } from './product-type-model';`